# Exiting if statement on failed validation in vb

Tags: vb.net, validation, if-statement

I am trying to validate user inputs with an if statement and all is well, except one thing. When the first error occurs, I would like the program to issue the message box with the error and then return the user to the input field with the error.

What it does currently is issue the error and then continue on to the rest of the errors.

I tried GoTo, and Break, End, but those are all undesired.

```
   Private Sub btnCalculateTicketRevenue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculateTicketRevenue.Click

    'Validate Adult Ticket Price user input

    Try
        If txtAdultTicketPrice.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text) = False Then
            'MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Adult ticket price", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            txtAdultTicketPriceError()
        ElseIf CLng(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text) < -1 Then
            'MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value greater than or equal to zero", "Negative value", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            txtAdultTicketPriceError()
        Else
            decAdultTicketPrice = CDec(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text)
            'MessageBox.Show(decAdultTicketPrice.ToString)
            blnPassedAdultTicketPrice = True
        End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong", "General Error")
        End
    End Try
```

Comment: Try `Return` instead. But it would be even better to look into Windows Forms Validation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Exit Sub`

```
Try
    If txtAdultTicketPrice.Text = "" Or IsNumeric(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value for Adult ticket price", "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf CLng(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text) < -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value greater than or equal to zero", "Negative value", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
    Else
        decAdultTicketPrice = CDec(txtAdultTicketPrice.Text)
        MessageBox.Show(decAdultTicketPrice.ToString)
        blnPassedAdultTicketPrice = True
    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong", "General Error")
    End
End Try
```